# Android Studio setText with String set in Code

Tags: java, android

Wanna set the text of a `TextView` to a string, set in my `MainActivity` like this:

```
String w1 = "Water";
```

Set the `TextView` in the `onCreate()`:

```
tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
```

Want to set the Text of a `TextView` in my `MainActivity` to the String w1.
Tried this: `tv.setText(w1)`, but doesn't work.

Should I do this with the string.xml file or can i do this like I've done it so far?

If I should do this with the string file, how should I do this?

---

This is the whole Code:

```
package name.verkaufsliste;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    public TextView tv1;
    public String w1 = "Water";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tv1= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        tv1.setText(w1)
        }
    }
```

---

my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="name.MainActivity">

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:ems="10" />
```

Comment: why isn't it working? can you post the entire class code?

Comment: Simply you can do this like this way tv.setText("String_Value");.. If you want to put same string in multiple place better practice to add string value in strings.xml file. Then you set tv.setText(R.string.String_name);

Comment: Your code should work ... May you have a problem with the Mainactivity.xml file. Can you post it?

Comment: You can check my answer.@Developer24

Comment: @KeLiuyue dont wanted to work with the string.xml file

Comment: You can try @David Lee answer .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the `strings.xml`

```
<resources>     
    <string name="water">water</string>
</resources>
```

Then

```
tv.setText(R.string.water);
```

EDITED:

more than like it this wouldn't work. You would want to do the following

```
tv.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.water));
```

Comment: I am using in listView Adapter but dont work for me because i cannot get getResources() in my listView Adapter

Comment: @Amin You can set Context as params of ListView's adapter .

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `XML` where the `TextView` its declared and add `android:text=`

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/my_textview"
  android:text="My Static Text" />
```

The correct and standard way its to use `string.xml` inside the `values` folder:

```
<resources>
    <string name="text_view">Hello</string>
</resources>
```

you can reference it like this:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/my_textview"
    android:text="@string/text_view" />
```

you can create different `values` folders for each language say `spanish`
 (`/values-es/strings.xml:`):

```
<resources>
    <string name="text_view">Hola!</string>
</resources>
```

with the same name and the text will change based on the language of the configuration of the cellphone, that is how [localization](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html) is handled.

To set it in the code you have to import first:

```
import android.widget.TextView;
```

then:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
tv.setText(R.string.text_view);
```

or in your case:

```
    String w1 = "Water";
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);
    tv.setText(w1);
```

notice you are missing the `TextView` declaration at the beggining unless you already have a `TextView tv;` somewhere else.

Comment: TextView declaration is there. Done it like your last example. didn't work.

Comment: did you try using `android:text="My Static Text"` in the `XML` ?

Answer (score 0):

**JAVA**

textview.setText(R.string.(string_name));

**Koltin**

tv.text = getString(R.string.(string_name))

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).